# How to create unmanaged class's object in a managed class?

Tags: c++, winforms

I am using Windows Forms for GUI for a C++ based app that works as backend for the form. The form is a Managed Class and the rest of the C++ code is unmanaged. I need to create an object of Unmanaged Class in the Managed Class(WinForm). How can I do that?

My (Relevant) Code :

```
#include "DataCapture.h"

public ref class LandingPage : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
  public:
    LandingPage(void) {
      InitializeComponent();
      this->dataCapture = new datacaptureapi::DataCapture();
      this->dataCapture->TurnOnResearchCapability();
    }

  private: static datacaptureapi::DataCapture* dataCapture;
};
```

Here, LandingPage is the Managed Class and DataCapture is the Unmanaged class.

Stuff I tried :

1. I tried adding & removing static, const, const static keywords and made/removed the unmanaged class's object as a pointer.
2. I tried using gcroot. The code would become :

`private: static gcroot<datacaptureapi::DataCapture*> dataCapture;
private: static gcroot<datacaptureapi::DataCapture> dataCapture;`

3. Added `#pragma unmanaged` on top of my class. Gave too many errors.

I read somewhere about writing a wrapper that will have same functions as my unmanaged class but it will be rewritten in .Net ecosystem, making it managed. I haven't tried that as I would like to use some simple method if possible. I dont think I really understood that either too :/

First time coding with WinForms, I am able to include my required `DataCapture.h` file and call the functions (if not in class). So the error is not because of linking or other setup problems.

Error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2028 unresolved token (0A0004D7) "public: __cdecl datacaptureapi::DataCapture::DataCapture(void)" (??0DataCapture@datacaptureapi@@$$FQEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: __clrcall FOVEImageCapture::LandingPage::LandingPage(void)" (??0LandingPage@FOVEImageCapture@@$$FQE$AAM@XZ)    FOVEImageCapture    C:\Users\kapil\Desktop\Project1\Project1\MyForm.obj 1

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2028 unresolved token (0A0004D8) "public: void __cdecl datacaptureapi::DataCapture::TurnOnResearchCapability(void)" (?TurnOnResearchCapability@DataCapture@datacaptureapi@@$$FQEAAXXZ) referenced in function "public: __clrcall FOVEImageCapture::LandingPage::LandingPage(void)" (??0LandingPage@FOVEImageCapture@@$$FQE$AAM@XZ)   FOVEImageCapture    C:\Users\kapil\Desktop\Project1\Project1\MyForm.obj 1
```

Code runs if I keep the given line in `private` and comment out the lines in constructor.

If I make the Unmanaged class' object as a non-pointer, I get the error :

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E2244   a member of a managed class cannot be of a non-managed class type   FOVEImageCapture    c:\Users\kapil\Desktop\Project1\Project1\MyForm.h   55  

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C4368   cannot define 'dataCapture' as a member of managed 'FOVEImageCapture::LandingPage': mixed types are not supported   FOVEImageCapture    c:\users\kapil\desktop\project1\project1\myform.h   55  

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2663   'datacaptureapi::DataCapture::DataCapture': 2 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer FOVEImageCapture    c:\users\kapil\desktop\project1\project1\myform.h   55
```

Comment: Do you use a Common Language Runtime Support? Is it a `/clr` or do you use any options?

Comment: I don't use any options.

Comment: So you use `/clr`, right? The `DataCapture` is placed in a separate libriary? Have you added dependency to a Project Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies?

Comment: Yes I use `/clr`. Yes I added the required dependency and I also included the header location.

Comment: It is just a basic linker error and doesn't have anything to do with the (correct) code snippet.  The linker simply cannot find the code for your unmanaged class.  Consider that you forgot to link its library.  The appearance of __cdecl in the link error messages is slightly funky, but normal when you target x64.  Be sure that you actually built the x64 flavor of the library.